# Libref is not assigned

Tags: sas, wrds, wrds-compusat

I was trying to inquiry data from TAQ, daily trade database. In SAS, I did the following but sas complained that, "Library  does not exist." I am sure that the path is correct.

```
%let wrds = wrds.wharton.upenn.edu 4016;options comamid = TCP remote=WRDS;
signon username=_prompt_;
*************************************************************************;
libname ct'/wrds/nyse/sasdata/taqms/ct';
rsubmit;
```

The log said:

```
NOTE: Libname CT refers to the same physical library as TAQMSE.
WARNING: Library CT does not exist.
NOTE: Libref CT was successfully assigned as follows:
      Engine:        V9
      Physical Name: C:\wrds\nyse\sasdata\taqms\ct
      rsubmit;
NOTE: Remote submit to WRDS commencing.
```

But when I first login into the wrds server, I saw the path, and the first engine gives the path of the library which I wanted to use. What did I do wrong in order to set up the library?

```
NOTE: Libref TAQMSEC was successfully assigned as follows:
      Levels:           5
      Engine(1):        V9
      Physical Name(1): /wrds/nyse/sasdata/taqms/ct
      Engine(2):        V9
      Physical Name(2): /wrds/nyse/sasdata/taqms/cq
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears as though you are trying to reference a remote library in your local session.  Try running the following AFTER the remote library has been assigned in the `rsubmit;` block (so, after the `endrsubmit;` statement):

```
 libname CT (TAQMSEC) server=WRDS;
```

Comment: right, thanks a lot, Allan. This solved the problem. I did not understand what rsubmit does.

Comment: "remote submit" - runs code on a different machine!